# Counting sort in C apparently works but binarysearch doesn't

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, cs50, counting-sort

I am looking for help regarding the implementation of a counting sort function in the CS50 Course in week 3.

An int Array has to be sorted.
I tested various unsorted arrays and my counting sort function seems to sort the array just correctly, yet my search functions won't work on the sorted array after.
Could someone give me a hint?

```
void countsort( int array[], int size) {

    int count=0;
    int zahl=0;
    int max=65536;
    int countarr [max];
    int finalarr [size];

    memset (countarr, 0, sizeof(countarr));

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        zahl=array[i];
        countarr[zahl]++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<max;i++) {

        while(countarr[i]>0) {
            finalarr[count]=i;
            countarr[i]--;
            count++;

        }
    }
    array=finalarr;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf(" %i ",array[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my search algorithm used after the array is sorted, it works with sort algorithms from other people.

```
bool binarysearch(int value, int values[], int n){

    int start=0,
        end=n,
        mid=0,
        midpos=0;

    while(end>0) {

        midpos=(start+end)/2; 

        mid=values[midpos];

        if(mid==value) return true;

        if(mid<value) start=++midpos;

        if(mid>value) end=--midpos;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an [mcve] containing only binary search where you hard-code the input array and the expected versus actual output? If your counting sort works, it's not at all relevant to this question. Also, now is probably a good time to learn to debug, having us debug for you won't teach you much. Also, there are probably a million code samples of binary search available online, you should probably just compare your code to one of those if debugging doesn't work.

Comment: Consider the case where `value` is larger than any value in `values`.

Comment: "give me a hint?" --> `end=n` is off by 1.

Comment: You should add a comment whether `end` is the highest index possibly containing the value, or one beyond. (And code accordingly.)

Comment: @Dukeling I tested the use of multiple search functions which are working perfect on my countsort so it is definitely not the problem I need to solve (first).

Answer (score 0):

1. In `binarysearch`, the loop condition `while(end>0)` is wrong.
   If we search for a value which is greater than at least one of the elements of the array, `end` will never be zero.
   Try changing it to `while(end>=start)`, which literally means that the considered interval is non-empty.
2. In `countsort`, the line `array=finalarr;` does not copy the whole array.
   Instead, the *local* variable `array` becomes a pointer to `finalarr`.
   The contents of the original array remain unchanged, and the sorted array is gone when you exit the function.
   This explains why your binary search works (better) with other sort functions.
   Try changing `finalarr[count]=i;` to `array[count]=i;` and get rid of `finalarr` completely, putting the values into `array` right away.
   Alternatively, you can use `memmove` instead of that line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it had to be only one small adjustment. :)